# Find Identity when using Merge

Tags: sql, t-sql, merge, output, identity

Sorry if this is a dupe, i took a gander at about 8 questions that didnt quite explain what i am looking for.

Destination Table (dTable)
aID bigint identity
bID bigint (primary Key)

@JSON Table
@Version Table

```
Merge into dTable t
using (select bid from @JSON) s
on t.bid = s.bid
when not matched
then insert(bid)
values (s.bid)
when matched
then update
set bid = s.bid

output
'dTable', @versionDate, action, inserted.bid, s.aid, @userid
into @version (tablename, versiondate, actiontaken, value, pk, userid)
;
```

Looking to grab the identity field of dTable where the values were updated or the identity was added.

s.aid returns a null, I think I would have to do something like isnull(inserted.aid, @@identity).  Due to the size of the project and my predecessor... I dont have much for a testing environment.

Tried @@Identity, scope_identity, not feeling the love.

Edit:  AID represents the identity im looking to snag, if a value doesnt exist IE: ColumnName (BID), then the BID (bigint value of human readable text) gets added causing a new columnID (AID) to be created.  For versioning purposes I would like to know that AID, as this AID will be associated (FK) to other tables like _order, _enabled, _unit, _type.

Comment: Where is the `s.` alias coming from?  It's not defined anywhere...

Comment: edited code.  merge into t (for target), using () s (for source)

Comment: There is an unclosed quote in the output clause, it's not clear where it should be closed, and you are inserting to a column `bid`, but there is no `bid` in your dTable definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your OUTPUT clause like this:

```
output 'dTable', @versionDate, action, inserted.bid, inserted.AID, @userid
into @version
```